# interesting SQL database usage queries

Tags: sql, usage-statistics

I am trying to generate some comprehensive information about my databases compile a list of interesting queries for database usage.

There is a log table with

```
date  
username  
servertime  
clienttime  
user query
```

as well as other tables that actually hold the query-able information.

Edit (for constructive subjectivity): **What is the most interesting usage stats query for the provided information?**

Some examples I have so far:

- Users per day,

  Queries per day

  Average query time per user

One suggestion per answer please; let me know if you want more information to work with.

Thanks!

Comment: This will be closed as it really does not belong here.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Where can I ask this that it will make sense?

Comment: On a forum, as stackoverflow is not a place for lengthy discussions with no answers.

Comment: So far there are 2 answers... are we a living contradiction?

Comment: @sova sometimes people will post to gain reputation on this site.  Other times people will post to share things that they find valuable.  This will most likely be closed when enough members with high rep vote to close it.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: you're probably right, but the quality of answers on SO is consistently high enough that I would ask elsewhere but I'm not convinced that, as the asker, I would benefit as much.  Considering the audience, I thought this was a good question

Comment: @sova fair enough however, the FAQ explicitly advises against these types of questions.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be more suitable for http://serverfault.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd be most interested in the top ten slowest queries.

Answer (score 0):

Users that use the most CPU time and/or run the most intensive queries.